# Campo Sent By (Enviado Por) en GMail con Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

Busque en este sitio, tanto en ingles como en español, también consulte la documentación de Google y nada.

Cuando uno usa GMail, puede dar permiso a otra persona a poder usar tu correo, eso incluye poder enviar correos en tu nombre, eso es lo que está pasando con el buzón de correo que tengo, es un buzón donde varias personas tienen acceso (10 personas) y pueden responder los correos que llegan, mi consulta es, ¿cómo puedo saber la cantidad de correos respondidos por cada persona que tiene acceso a este buzón?

Estoy usando GMail Meter (con varias modificaciones adaptadas a mi necesidad) para poder obtener varios datos, pero lo que no e podido obtener es ese campo.

En la captura de pantalla puedes ver lo siguiente:

[image]

Lo que necesito es listar todos los "enviado por otrocorreo@dominio.com"

Comment: Decir que has "...buscado en varios foros..." no ayuda en nada. Sería mejor que indicaras en cuales has buscado, si están en inglés o español, las páginas de la documentación que has consultado, en fin, algo breve pero específico. ¿A qué te refieres con "buzón de correo que uso es compartido"?  Tampoco queda claro de dónde tomaste la captura de pantalla. Favor consultar [ask].

Comment: Para poder logar esto, es necesario usar la API de GMAIL y extraer los encabezados de los mensajes. Cada mensaje tendrá el encabezado el cual buscas y podras extraer la información y usarla a tu antojo. Sin embargo, lo que estas haciendo no es la forma recomendada de usar tu bandeja. Te recomiendo mucho que uses Google Groups mejor.

Comment: @Morfinismo: Me parece que has mal interpretado lo que está haciendo el autor de la pregunta. Según entiendo, está haciendo uso de la función de delegación, la cual es una característica soportada. Más detalles en https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=es

Comment: Muchas gracias Rubén, es la función que usamos aquí, lamentablemente no encuentro como obtener el campo ENVIADO POR, seguiré investigando.

Comment: Juan: Como autor de la pregunta tu recibes en automático una notificación por cada comentario publicado, pero los otros usuarios deben ser mencionados usando `@` como prefijo. Mas detalles en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/65

Answer (score 0):

Sé que [getRawContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getrawcontent) devuelve el contenido equivalente a "ver el original", pero no he tenido oportunidad de reproducir el problema para dar una respuesta más completa.

Teniendo un correo con las características en cuestión, busca el nombre/dirección de correo de quien envió el mensaje para que identifiques la cabecera del mensaje la cual seguramente usará el prefijo "X-". Una vez identificado la estructura de la cabecera podrás usar una expresión regular para extraer el dato.

Referencias

- [What do X-headers in mails stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14469110/1595451)